# Differentiating between user input methods.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on a web application using ASP.Net (C#) for assigning cards.

A user can swipe a card using a magnetic swipe card reader to fill in a text box, and depending on the card existing in the application database, attach a card to a customer profile.

The same process can be completed if a user manually enters the card number into the text box without assistance.

To prevent user error, I am looking into adding a validation number for each card.

My problem concerns differentiating between manual input versus a card reader. Obviously a user is not going to want to enter a validation code manually if they have swiped, whereas manual input should always be checked with the validation code.

I have tested using a timer when a user is focused on the card number text box to determine which input method has been used, but before I go ahead with this implementation I want to check for any better alternatives.

As a final note, the user could be repeating this process many times.

Comment: Sorry, but where is the question??

Comment: I am asking if there are any better alternatives to timing how the long a user has focused on a textbox

Comment: :) I can see an image of customer intensely staring at a textbox for 42 seconds... than textbox's border getting darker... start smoking... and burst into flames due to user being too focused on it.

Comment: I thought the same when I reread my comment

Comment: More seriously why it has to be the same text field at all? Can't you have 2 separate ones?

Comment: I understand I have not fully described my page. I have a text box for the card number, which upon triggering the text changed event, the validation code text box then prompts the user for the card code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you write the code that reads the card? If so...

You could edit that code to also set a hidden check box on the page that indicates if a validation code is required. This being the case the validation code box becomes available to the user to enter said code. This way you check that a code is required and that a code has been provided before submission.

Comment: As far as I understand how the magnetic card reader works, it is acting as a keyboard. I do like your idea of the hidden check box though, that idea had not occurred to me.

Comment: It's been nearly a month since I asked this question and this answer is the closest I received. I checked for a special symbol added by the card encoder, and used that to differentiate between automatic and manual input. Thanks for your answer.